# Sync facebook comment on my website from the facebook that shares the same URL

Tags: php, facebook, web, facebook-comments

I have a facebook comment on my website. here is the sample: http://www.obtainer-online.com/fbtest.php

Is it possible to sync the comment on my website on that particular URL and the comment from the facebook that shares that URL?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You would need to copy the comments, but for that you would need the login data (or an access token) of every commenter ;)